# Add a Close > Bug category?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ability to close a question as a bug report.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/436/ability-to-close-a-question-as-a-bug-report)

There are many questions that should really be filed as bug reports instead. Currently, these are closed as "off topic". Wouldn't it be better to have a Close > Bug category? For one thing, it might seem like a friendlier way of pushing users onto Launchpad than simply saying its off topic and please go away. :)

Another thing is that some users might not actually follow through and report the bug. It might be useful if someone had a look at the list after some time and see if the bug was reported.

Just an idea.