# Checking version of Ubuntu before posting a question

Tags: feature-request

At least 10 per cent of the questions asked on AskUbuntu are for an unsupported version of Ubuntu or Linux or even another OS. It would be nice to have an automatic check in AskUbuntu that will force the poster to specify the version of the OS in question and **automatically reject** the question if this is not about a supported version.

This will save huge amount of time for the people trying to help and eliminate comments like "what is your version?", "you cannot post this question here because of this and that".

Comment: Kinda related post: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19447/

Comment: We should be able to post a Ubuntu question to AskUbuntu even if we're currently using an obsolete version of Windows, and the Ubuntu system is elsewhere.